# Как открыть второе активити

Tags: java, android, activity

Не получается запустить вторую активность.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(c, holder.nametxt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Этот способ не работает, ругается на `FirstActivity.this`.

В манифесте прописана вторая активность, даже пробовал запускать сначала вторую активность-запускается.

Запустить нужно с `TextDim`  класса вот начало:

```
public class TextDim {
    public static class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {
        public String TAG = "MyLogs";
```

Comment: пытался в манифесте с intent-filter не получилось. или не правильно написал

Comment: Toast.makeText выводит правильно

Comment: Рахим не спорь он тебе дело говорит  пропиши место C какой нибудь класс и убедишься

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Этот способ не работает, ругается на `FirstActivity.this`.

И правильно *ругается*, так как в классе `TextDim` нет никакой `FirstActivity.this`.

Судя по всему, в методе `onClick(...)` у Вас есть нужный объект – `c`, вот его и передавайте первым параметром в конструктор при создании интента:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(c, SecondActivity.class);
```

Также Вы можете получить необходимый контекст от `View v`:

```
Context context = v.getContext();
```

---

При создании интента Вы используете конструктор:

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)
```

первым параметром которого является экземпляр субкласса класса `Context`. В качестве этого параметра Вы можете передать либо ссылку на активити, либо ссылку на объект класса `Application`, либо ссылку на любой другой объект, в иерархии наследования которого присутствует класс `Context`, либо его субклассы.

А по-хорошему, хранить где-либо ссылку на активити – весьма плохая практика, ибо при изменении конфигурации устройства (повороты экрана и т.д.), активити создастся заново, однако GC не сможет уничтожить старую активити из-за того, что ссылка на нее где-то до сих пор присутствует, и получите Вы memory leak.

Для запуска активити из любого места я бы посоветовал использовать `ApplicationContext`, который Вы можете получить в любом месте таким образом:

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    private static Context sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Хотя Google и не рекомендует без особой необходимости переопределять класс `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Использование в коде `FirstActivity.this` указывает на то, что событие `onClick()` в исходной версии кода обрабатывалось анонимным или внутренним классом, затем ТС сделал *copy-paste* вынес все в класс и естественно все перестало работать :)

В общем за это я и минусовал топикстартёра - за то что не включает голову.

Если кому-то не нравится за что я поставил минус - можете меня тоже минусовать, welcome!